# Is it possible to access to private scoped variables or methods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I have a third-party library that exposes a public method that points to a private one.

```
  const thirdPartyLibrary = function(){
      function privateFunction() {
        return superSecretFunction();
      };
      function superSecretFunction() {
        return Math.random();
      };
      // library public api
      return {
        publicMethod:() => { return privateFunction() }
      }
    }();
```

I've simplified it a bit in the example, but it's something like an implementation of the Module Pattern.
I wonder if it is possible to somehow access these private methods to change their behavior or at least to expose them.

I have tried to access `this` but as expected the private methods are not listed.

```
thirdPartyLibrary.foo = function(){console.log(this)};
thirdPartyLibrary.foo() // private members not listed
```

Obviously, I cannot change the library's code :)

Comment: it's called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), and generally the answer is no. But it depends on the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Closure-scoped variables really are private.

All you can do is access (and overwrite) the methods of the `thirdPartyLibrary` object, which is created by the "*library public api*" object literal. This means you can completely replace the whole library with your own version if you need to, but you cannot access its internals<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>1: Some libraries accidentally leak their internals, e.g. by calling callbacks with an internal as the `this` context, but that's a bug in the module implementation.</sub>

Comment: This "Closure-scoped variables really are private"